# How to successfully install angular2-material?

Tags: angular

I am using: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

I want to use angular2-material, I know there is a branch with angular2-material2 in that project, but I want to just add it in myself. Issue is when I do:

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
+-- @angular/material@2.0.0-alpha.9-3
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-rc.1
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@4.0.0-dev.0
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.14: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/core@2.1.0 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.1.0 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.1.0 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of tslint@^3.9.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN tslint-loader@2.1.5 requires a peer of tslint@^3.0.0 but none was installed.
```

package.json is here:

```
{
name: "angular2-webpack-starter",
version: "5.0.5",
description: "An Angular 2 Webpack Starter kit featuring Angular 2 (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E, Coverage), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, Istanbul, TypeScript, and Webpack by AngularClass",
-keywords: (3)[
"angular2",
"webpack",
"typescript"
],
author: "Patrick Stapleton <patrick@angularclass.com>",
homepage: https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter,
license: "MIT",
-scripts: {
build:dev: "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
build:docker: "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
build:prod: "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
build: "npm run build:dev",
ci: "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
clean:dist: "npm run rimraf -- dist",
clean:install: "npm set progress=false && npm install",
clean:start: "npm start",
clean: "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist",
docker: "docker",
docs: "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
e2e:live: "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
e2e: "npm run protractor",
github-deploy:dev: "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-dev",
github-deploy:prod: "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --github-prod",
github-deploy: "npm run github-deploy:dev",
lint: "npm run tslint "src/**/*.ts"",
postversion: "git push && git push --tags",
prebuild:dev: "npm run clean:dist",
prebuild:prod: "npm run clean:dist",
preclean:install: "npm run clean",
preclean:start: "npm run clean",
pree2e: "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
preversion: "npm test",
protractor: "protractor",
rimraf: "rimraf",
server:dev:hmr: "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
server:dev: "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
server:prod: "http-server dist --cors",
server: "npm run server:dev",
start:hmr: "npm run server:dev:hmr",
start: "npm run server:dev",
test: "karma start",
tslint: "tslint",
typedoc: "typedoc",
version: "npm run build",
watch:dev:hmr: "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
watch:dev: "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
watch:prod: "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
watch:test: "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
watch: "npm run watch:dev",
webdriver-manager: "webdriver-manager",
webdriver:start: "npm run webdriver-manager start",
webdriver:update: "npm run webdriver-manager update",
webpack-dev-server: "webpack-dev-server",
webpack: "webpack"
},
-dependencies: {
@angular/common: "2.1.0",
@angular/compiler: "2.1.0",
@angular/core: "2.1.0",
@angular/forms: "^2.1.0",
@angular/http: "2.1.0",
@angular/platform-browser: "2.1.0",
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: "2.1.0",
@angular/platform-server: "2.1.0",
@angular/router: "3.1.0",
@angularclass/conventions-loader: "^1.0.2",
@angularclass/hmr: "~1.2.0",
@angularclass/hmr-loader: "~3.0.2",
assets-webpack-plugin: "^3.4.0",
core-js: "^2.4.1",
http-server: "^0.9.0",
ie-shim: "^0.1.0",
rxjs: "^5.0.0-rc.1",
zone.js: "~0.6.17"
},
-devDependencies: {
@types/hammerjs: "^2.0.33",
@types/jasmine: "^2.2.34",
@types/node: "^6.0.38",
@types/protractor: "^1.5.20",
@types/selenium-webdriver: "2.44.29",
@types/source-map: "^0.1.27",
@types/uglify-js: "^2.0.27",
@types/webpack: "^1.12.34",
angular2-template-loader: "^0.5.0",
awesome-typescript-loader: "^2.2.1",
codelyzer: "~1.0.0-beta.2",
copy-webpack-plugin: "^3.0.1",
css-loader: "^0.25.0",
exports-loader: "^0.6.3",
expose-loader: "^0.7.1",
file-loader: "^0.9.0",
gh-pages: "^0.11.0",
html-webpack-plugin: "^2.21.0",
imports-loader: "^0.6.5",
istanbul-instrumenter-loader: "^1.0.0",
json-loader: "^0.5.4",
karma: "^1.2.0",
karma-chrome-launcher: "^2.0.0",
karma-coverage: "^1.1.1",
karma-jasmine: "^1.0.2",
karma-mocha-reporter: "^2.0.0",
karma-remap-coverage: "^0.1.1",
karma-sourcemap-loader: "^0.3.7",
karma-webpack: "1.8.0",
parse5: "^2.2.2",
protractor: "^4.0.9",
raw-loader: "0.5.1",
rimraf: "^2.5.2",
script-ext-html-webpack-plugin: "^1.3.2",
source-map-loader: "^0.1.5",
string-replace-loader: "1.0.5",
style-loader: "^0.13.1",
to-string-loader: "^1.1.4",
ts-helpers: "1.1.2",
ts-node: "^1.3.0",
tslint: "^4.0.0-dev.0",
tslint-loader: "^2.1.3",
typedoc: "^0.5.0",
typescript: "^2.0.3",
url-loader: "^0.5.7",
webpack: "2.1.0-beta.25",
webpack-dev-middleware: "^1.6.1",
webpack-dev-server: "^2.1.0-beta.9",
webpack-md5-hash: "^0.0.5",
webpack-merge: "^0.14.1"
},
-repository: {
type: "git",
url: https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git
},
-bugs: {
url: https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues
},
-engines: {
node: ">= 4.2.1",
npm: ">= 3"
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your package.json file here?

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: That's odd: why aren't your `package.json` keys quoted? This is not valid JSON (example: `prebuild:dev: "npm run clean:dist"`, which is the key?). It may still work, somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In npm v3, a package's `peerDepencency` tree [is no longer installed automatically](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5), so you'll need to install those modules yourself:

```
npm -i --save-dev rxjs@5.0.0-rc.1 tslint@4.0.0-dev.0
```

Those are not errors, those are `WARN`s. I'd wager `npm ls` still shows a line like `@angular/material@2.0.0-alpha.9-3 node_modules/@angular/material`.